# Designing a website with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to design a website with bootstrap like the course

while watching the tutorial

he typed

```
 <div class="container homepage">
```

and when he oppened the css file

he typed

```
.homepage{
  text-align: center;
}
```

but i couldn't call it

if i have

```
<div class="container homepage">
```

how can i call it in the css file to make the style !

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Let's Code </title>

    <!-- this our google font and Font-awesome -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!-- <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script> -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://www.foxpic.com/V0PSDLRS.png" border="0" alt="One Million Lines" title="One Million Lines" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Get involved</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Our goal is to inspire <br>Tallahassee to write 1,000,000<br> lines of code_</h1>
        <p>All over the country people are taking the <strong>HOUR OF CODE</strong> challenge issued by <strong>CODE.org</strong>. Millions of lines of code are being written. In the capital of Florida, Tallahassee, the community is taking the challenge and our goal is to write 1,000,000 lines of code_</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        <img src="http://www.foxpic.com/V0ROP7Fw.png" border="0" alt="Code.org" />  

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container hompage">
    <h2>Get Involved</h2>  
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- grid.html the bootstrap based 12 columns important -->
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>
          <h2>Students</h2>
          <p>Want to learn how to code? Want to help us get to 1,000,000 lines? Click the button below and we'll let you know how to get involved. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="grid.html" role="button">Start Learning &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>
          <h2>Educators</h2>
          <p>Want to bring this initiative to your school or institution? Awesome! Click the button below and we'll make it happen. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" role="button">Join the Initiative &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-money fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>          
          <h2>Sponsors</h2>
          <p>We love all the support we get to help host more events, and empower more lives with the knowledge of coding. Click to get involved.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Jc5emQqf1e43PHM5US6Rrss2vXGmYNhI1o5GLIckmho/viewform?usp=send_form" target="_blank" role="button">Give Support &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the css file : (custom.ss)

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.nav{
  font-family: 'Arvo',courier,serif;
}
ul.nav{
  font-size: 13px;
}
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(http://www.foxpic.com/V1rV3XC8.jpg);
  color: white;

}
.jumbotron h1{
  font-family: 'Arvo', courier, serif;
}
.jumbotron h1{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
} 
.jumbotron p{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding : 0 50px;
}
.btn-lg {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.homepage{
  text-align: center;
}
.homepage h2{
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-family: 'Arvo', courier ,serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code right? Seems to me you are writing something wrong. Code you own .css file here and your .html and we will see. Besides, did you import your .css file into the .html?

Comment: @tomasyany i edited it look now :)

Comment: @smile How are you serving this html file?

Comment: i don't know what you mean with serving ? you mean how i open it ? http://localhost/firstweb/

Comment: @smile That is what I mean, yes; I wanted to make sure  you opened it correctly(as in served through a web-server), in order to rule out a possibility.   Have you made any attempt at debugging through your browser's css inspector?

Comment: @smile Then please do so; right click the element that should be centered->inspect element(assuming you're using chrome or firefox), from there, look at the css rules and see what rule is overriding your css, assuming it is correctly imported.

Comment: Press Ctrl+U to look at the source code of the page, and click on the `<link>` rule where you import your CSS. See if you can open the CSS, to see if it's properly linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, you have:

```
<div class="container hompage">
```

It should be:

```
<div class="container homepage">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hfxvad8d/

Comment: can you tell me why he didn't type .container homepage{} instead of .homepage{} i thought it will be error !

Comment: Because a style such as `.container .homepage {}` would only apply to markup such as `<div class="container"><div class="homepage">`

Comment: can i ask for more clarification  ?

Comment: @smile Sure... CSS code such as `.container .homepage {}` is meant to specify an HTML element with the class "homepage" that is nested inside of an HTML element with the class "container". If you wanted to specify styles for an HTML element that had both classes, you'd specify `.container.homepage {}` instead. (Note that the second example has no space between the class names.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo.
The div class should be .homepage not .hompage